# TypeError while Implement startWith() operator in rxjs

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I am quite a beginner at angular and I am just trying to create an Observable and run it automatically just the first time when a particular condition is not met.

but typescript throws some errors while I use startWith() and I don't understand what to do now?

`this.obsearable$ = this.id ? from(this.pt.get(this.id)) : from([]).pipe(startWith())`

**Error:**
Argument of type 'Observable' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction<any, unknown>'.

Type 'Observable' provides no match for the signature '(source: Observable): Observable'.ts(2345)

Comment: The snippet shared is not clear to address that. startWith operator ensures you get the value you specify in the operator. Your case says: from empty array start with nothing.. seems confusing..

Answer (score 1):

The `startWith()` operator is intended for observables that may not emit an initial value. In the case of your example, `from()` immediately emits the value contained inside its parameter, so there is no need to use `startWith()`.

Answer (score 0):

`startWith` works only with some value (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/startwith)